# After migrate database on WordPress I can't access my wp-admin page

Tags: wordpress

I used migrate database to move my site from my localhost to my host server.

My host server uses cPanel. I used the migrate database plugin to import the database from my localhost and I can access the homepage but get this error after logging to to get to my wp_admin page

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

Steps I followed was

1. Exported the WordPress 4.9.1 site on my pc using migrate DB
2. Created a new instance of WordPress 4.9.1 on my host server and added migrate db plugin
3. On phpmyadmin I imported the file from migrate db in step2
4. I had to change the table prefixes on my host server
5. I could login and see the homepage but couldn't access any wp-admin page so I checked usernames and passwords in wp_users/wp_options table and could see the mismatch
6. Checked wp_config for mismatch of names but could see anything

Comment: looks like you have a permission issue, check your folder / file permissions

Comment: there may be sevelar issues with error. first of all, check `wp_usermeta` table. username, which you're trying to use, may not have permissions such as `administrator` to access into dashboard. also, try to login using `{your-website}.com/wp-login.php` link.

Comment: it worked if i have the same username/password on both wordpress websites . I have admin access in wp_usermeta

Answer (score 1):

Apart from checking that wp_users and wp_usermeta tables are in sync in the database, you also need to check a value in the wp_options table.

In that table is a value wp_user_roles that has an array value.

You said you have created a new WP install, and you needed to change the table name prefix.

Very probably, you are using your own table name prefix. If that is the case, you will need to change the value name wp_user_roles in the yourprefix_options table to yourprefix_user_roles. You can leave the value untouched.

That should get you back up to speed again.